# Variable Selection using Olssr in R

Tags: r, variables, linear-regression

I have this linear regression problem which has around 500-600 independent variables. What would be the best way for variable selection for the model using R. I am currently trying to perform Stepwise regression using the 'Olssr' package in R but keep getting this error:

```
 >ols_all_subset(mylogit)
 Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
 invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
 In addition: Warning message:
 In combn(n, r[i]) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

Answer (score 1):

Accodring to [olsrr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/olsrr/olsrr.pdf) documentation, `ols_all_subset`

> Fits all regressions involving one regressor, two regressors, three regressors, and so on. It tests all possible subsets of the set of potential independent variables.

For 500 - 600 variables there are 2^500 > 10^150 possible combinations, which would simply take too much time. For stepwise variable selection, use rather [ols_stepwise](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/olsrr/versions/0.3.0/topics/ols_stepwise)

Comment: I have tried all the ols procedures possible, all of them keep showing the same error

Comment: What kind of data causes the error? Did you try with a subset of the data?